# Why does `color-scheme: dark` cause <object>s to have white backgrounds in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, svg

I have a site which uses `<object>` to render external SVGs, many of which have transparent backgrounds. I added the CSS property `color-scheme: dark`, indicating that it ["can be rendered using the operating system dark color scheme"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color-scheme). However, in Chrome/Blink, this results in the `<object>` elements having white backgrounds! This is a minimal demo:

```css
:root {
  background-color: blue;
  
  /*
    In Chrome/Edge, the following makes the <object> have a white background!
    In Firefox/Safari, it stays transparent.
  */
  color-scheme: dark;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<object
  type="image/svg+xml"
  data="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg version='1.1' width='300' height='200' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Ccircle cx='150' cy='100' r='80' fill='green' /%3E%3C/svg%3E%0A">
  SVG not supported
</object>
```

What's going on here? Is this a bug in Chromium? Or is there something about `<object>`, SVG, or `color-scheme` that I have misunderstood?

Comment: Okay, I decided it's a browser bug. Reported at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1279874

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this too, and this post was about the only thing I could find regarding this specific issue. Posting a semi-fix to help others.
I was able to find a work-around *IF* your background color is solid (not a gradient or image).

I added a background-color style directly to the SVG — in my case via the  tag, citing the SVG itself via an ID tag. Said color matched the background-color that my SVG object tag is contained in. This style was scoped via the dark-mode media query.
Incidentally, I had to cache-bust the `<object>` tag's data src. Adding a query string did that. EG: ?v.22.4.6

Here's an example of how I was able to get around the bug:

**SVG in Object in Header** (it's a logo, note the cache busting query is optional)

```
<header style="background-color:#00053E">
  <object type="image/svg+xml" data="../the/link/to-your.svg?v22.6.3">
      ...
```

**The SVG the object embeds:**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="SVG-ID-HERE" viewBox="0 0 291 31"  preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
    <style type="text/css">
        @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark)
        {
            #SVG-ID-HERE{ background-color: #00053E }
        }
    </style>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I have just came across same issue. Based on @fregante answer in [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69591128/chrome-is-forcing-a-white-background-on-frames-only-on-some-websites) all you need to do is add **color-scheme: light** or **color-scheme: normal** to the **object** css style.

Here is your example without white background

```css
:root {
  background-color: blue;
  
  /*
    In Chrome/Edge, the following makes the <object> have a white background!
    In Firefox/Safari, it stays transparent.
  */
  color-scheme: dark;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}

object {
  color-scheme: light; /*<--Add this to fix WHITE BG issue*/
}
```

```html
<object
  type="image/svg+xml"
  data="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg version='1.1' width='300' height='200' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Ccircle cx='150' cy='100' r='80' fill='green' /%3E%3C/svg%3E%0A">
  SVG not supported
</object>
```

Comment: Give an effective explanation and the best answer you can. Offer the best response you can to any open-ended or newly added questions

Answer (score 0):

Little late, but i found that if you put on the css:

```
object {
  color-scheme: light;
}
```

It's fix the issue! I fixed this thanks to this post, and your right diagnosis for the problem! Thanks!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Lol @ the bot asking for clarification and citations for a single line of self explanatory CSS