# Ionic Framework: Cannot create a IFrame with transparent Background

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, iframe, background

I am currently trying to create a website with Ionic Framework using React where I need to have a transparent iFrame inside the website. I have tried many ways and all result in a white background.

The issue seems to be in a way ionic Framework works because I have tried the same snippets in vanilla React and it worked as intentional.

I have tried everything from setting **allowTransparency="true"** to changing the IFrame background to transparent but it doesn't seem to work. Always resulting in a white background.

I tried with this small snippet

**HTML**

```
 <div className="container">
     <iframe className='iframe' allowTransparency src="about:blank"></iframe>
 </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 300px;
}

.iframe {
  background: transparent;
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
}
```

**Results:**

1. In case of [Vanilla (normal) React](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CB5oe.png) the background is transparent and only border of the iframe is visible
2. In case of [Ionic Framework with React](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ow0EA.png) the background remains white

**Update:**

The solution is to use the same color-scheme for the iframe as the original DOM. Best explained by Neea here https://stackoverflow.com/a/69671458/14341569